# Allow only a subset of HTML tags in ASP.Net textarea

Tags: html, asp.net, regex, editor

I need to allow certain HTML tags in my textarea and ignore all other tags.
For example < b > will be allowed, but if < h1 > is there I want the tag replaced by its inner text.

< b >some text< /b> will be:  **some text**
and < h1 > some text < /h1 > will be: some text

I also want all attributes extracted out form all allowed tags.

Is this possible in regex?

**Update:** I tried this negative lookahead `<(?!b|br|p|i|u|sup|sub|br|ul|ol|li|a).*(\s[^>]*)?>` but it matches the entire document. it would be great if someone could fix that negative lookahead.

Comment: html is not parsed with regex..use an html parser..also make your question specific.right now you are asking a lot and we would have to close this ans unless you edit it and make it more specific

Comment: It can hardly be called 'parsing'. No pairing is required. I only need to detect individual tags.

Comment: How would you parse (pardon) detect:  `<h1><b>some text</b></h1>` ?

Comment: Well, for my case it would be enough to find and remove all <h1> open tags and also all </h1> close tags. Since I do not need to pair open tags with close tags I though regex would  fit in.
I want a regex that will match <not(b|br|p)>. that's all I need!

Comment: I tried this negative lookahead <(?!b|br|p|i|u|sup|sub|br|ul|ol|li|a).*(\s[^>]*)?>
but it matches the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

I found my way through this.

In case someone else would need this in the future here is what I did.

```
        // remove HTML comments
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"<!--[^-]*-->", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        input = regex.Replace(input, "");
        // remove unsupported tags
        regex = new Regex(@"</?((?!p|i|u|sup|sub|br|ol|li|a|b|/)|((p|i|sup|sub|br|ul|ol|li|a|b)[^<>\s]+))[^<>]*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        input = regex.Replace(input, "");
        // remove attribiutes
        regex = new Regex(@"(<[^\s]+)(\s[^<>]*)(>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        input = regex.Replace(input, m => m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[3].Value);
        return input;
```